# How to keep an item counter in a collection when deleting with the Admin SDK

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

The function of deleting an item in firestore, returns correctly even if the item to be deleted don't exist.

If we delete a number of elements in a batch and we have a counter of elements of the collection that we want to update, in case some element that we are going to delete no longer exists, the counter would give a smaller number of the real one.

To avoid this, we use the following firestore rule:

allow delete: if exists (/ databases / $ (database) / documents / ...);

The problem is that if we run the batch on the server, the Admin SDK ignores the firestore rules.

Any solution that does not involve transactions?

Answer (score 0):

How about using a cloud function that listens for deletes?

The way this would work is you set up a listener that waits on specific collections to have a document deleted. This would be a great way to guarantee a delete leads to a function being run, and the function can do anything you'd like (e.g. increment/decrement, etc.).

This could very simply look like this:

```
    exports.deletedItem = functions.firestore
               .document('items/{itemId}')
               .onDelete((snap, context) => {

                  const deletedValue = snap.data();
                  // Increment/decrement anything you'd like here.
                  // Perform any number of operations on a confirmed delete
               });
```